# Remove duplicate items from an array of items

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to create an array of templates that refer to a particular rendering. In some templates, renderings are placed twice. So, array contains 2 copies of same templates.
What is the sitecore powershell command to remove duplicate items from an array of sitecore items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply remove the duplicate items from the array by using `Sort-Object` with the
`-Unique` switch, It will combine sorting with the removal of duplicates. Alias of `Sort-Object` is `sort` -

```
$YourItemArrayList | sort -unique
```